# Sublime text 2 - share configuration with two computers and more

Tags: sublimetext2

I am working on Sublime Text 2 at home and at work. I need the same configuration on both computers. When I change something at home, I want to see this change at work and vice versa. I think I can do something like that with [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29)?

I need to share user configuration, user bindings, snippest and plugins installed by Package Control. How can I share the configuration between two computers and more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend putting your files in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or any similar file-syncing service.

(I do exactly this with [AutoHotKey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) scripts, and it works really well.)

There is [a thread on the SublimeText forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7248) that asks the same question, and in there, an answer refers to the page [Using Dropbox to synchronise Sublime Text settings across Windows computers](http://juhap.iki.fi/misc/using-dropbox-to-sync-sublime-text-settings-across-windows-computers/), saying "I don't have any issue with this method."

Other suggestions mentioned in that thread are:

- Keeping your configuration in an online version-control system (such as [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) or [Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket)) - but it warns "some plugins does contain some private infos (SFTP plugin, for example, keeps its license into the user's folder)"
- "For whatever it's worth, I use the Windows portable version and dump the whole of it into my Dropbox."
- Using a [shell script to do the sync between OS X and Linux](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/24/sync-and-back-up-sublime-text-settings-and-plug-ins-using-dropbox-on-linux-and-osx/)

Comment: But is it work with Package Control? If i install something on computer1 it will be also work on computer2, when both Sublime Text 2 work on the same share folder configuration by dropbox?

Comment: I've added some more info - the answer would appear to be "yes"!

Comment: Dropbox + Portable Sublime Text = Happy Synchronicity

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [solution](http://misfoc.us/post/18018400006/syncing-sublime-text-2-settings-via-dropbox) in order to sync between Windows and Mac